# I use Colab and Plotly and I want save a Plotly figure - how to install plotly-orca in Colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I get the error message below.

If you haven't installed orca yet, you can do so using conda as follows:

```
$ conda install -c plotly plotly-orca
```

Alternatively, see other installation methods in the orca project README at
https://github.com/plotly/orca.

I tried:
`!pip install plotly-orca`, but that throws an error.

Collecting plotly-orca
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plotly-orca (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for plotly-orca

What I want to do:

- Save a Plotly figure locally in Google Drive

Comment: I've answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262385/saving-or-downloading-plotly-iplot-images-on-google-colaboratory/57272111#57272111

Answer (score 0):

**To save an iplotly graph as html to gdrive**

```
# Connecting to GDrive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

from plotly.offline import iplot, plot, download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode
import plotly.graph_objs as go


Tickets_plot = go.Figure( ..... whatever is normally for your Plotly graph ....)

# this saves it to Google Drive ...you can put it in any folder you like
plot(Tickets_plot, filename="/content/drive/test.html", auto_open=False)

# this saves it within the notebook folder locallhy
plot(Tickets_plot, filename="/content/drive/test.html", auto_open=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
!pip install plotly==4.4.1
!wget https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases/download/v1.2.1/orca-1.2.1-x86_64.AppImage -O /usr/local/bin/orca
!chmod +x /usr/local/bin/orca
```