# Saving or downloading plotly iplot images on Google Colaboratory

Tags: download, plotly, google-colaboratory

I have been attempting to download a plot created using plotly on google colaboratory. So far this is what I have attempted:

I have tried changing

```py
files.download('foo.svg')
```

to

```py
files.download('foo')
```

and I still get no results. I navigated to the files on Google colab and nothing shows there

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from google.colab import files

def enable_plotly_in_cell():
  import IPython
  from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''<script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>'''))
  init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

#this actually shows the plot 
enable_plotly_in_cell()

N = 500
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.randn(N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
df.head()

data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['x'], # assign x as the dataframe column 'x'
        y=df['y']
    )
]

iplot(data,image = 'svg', filename = 'foo')

files.download('foo.svg')
```

This is the error I am getting:

```py
OSErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-31523eb02a59> in <module>()
     29 iplot(data,image = 'svg', filename = 'foo')
     30 
---> 31 files.download('foo.svg')
     32 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/colab/files.pyc in download(filename)
    140     msg = 'Cannot find file: {}'.format(filename)
    141     if _six.PY2:
--> 142       raise OSError(msg)
    143     else:
    144       raise FileNotFoundError(msg)  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable

OSError: Cannot find file: foo.svg
```

Comment: I can navigate on the plotly menu to the 'download plot as a png' option but I get a really low quality plot

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To save vector or raster images (e.g. SVGs or PNGs) from Plotly figures you need to have [Kaleido](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido) (preferred) *or* [Orca](https://github.com/plotly/orca) (legacy) installed, which is actually possible using the following commands in Colab:

*Kaleido*:

```
!pip install kaleido
```

*Orca*:

```
!pip install plotly>=4.0.0
!wget https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases/download/v1.2.1/orca-1.2.1-x86_64.AppImage -O /usr/local/bin/orca
!chmod +x /usr/local/bin/orca
!apt-get install xvfb libgtk2.0-0 libgconf-2-4
```

Once *either of the above* is done you can use the following code to make, show and export a figure (using `plotly` version 4):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure( go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,3,2] ) )
fig.show()
fig.write_image("image.svg")
fig.write_image("image.png")
```

The files can then be downloaded with:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('image.svg')
files.download('image.png')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Great! Feel free to vote for and/or accept the answer :)

Comment: I am attempting your solution. The first three lines of installing orca work fine. But the fourth gives me an error. "E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xorg-server/xvfb_1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]"

Comment: Just make sure to change the version to the latest one (now it is 4.7.1). This works now on Colab.

Comment: I still needed to specify the orca executable location. `import plotly.io as pio
pio.orca.config.executable = '/usr/local/bin/orca'`

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it strange that we have to use `files.download('image.svg')` to download the data eventually? I am used to files appearing in my google colab file browser, after I create them. And them I can just tell google drive to download them to my computer. But the plotly figures don't appear in the file browser after doing `fig.write_image("image.svg")`. How come?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it does work for me:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(...) # plot your fig

go.Figure.write_html(fig,"file.html") # write as html or image
files.download("file.html") # download your file and give me a vote my answer
```